# Formatted vs unformatted string C

Tags: c, string

I have a `char * temp_string` where I keep these chars: `Hello\nWor'ld\\\042` including `\0` at the end.

This is the way I make my string:

```
char * addDataChunk(char * data,char c)
{
    char * p;
    if(data==NULL)
    {
        if(!(data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*2))){
            printf("malloc error\n");
            throwInternError();
        }
        data[0]=c;
        data[1]='\0';
        return data;
    }
    else
    {
        if((p = (char*)realloc(data,((strlen(data)+2)*sizeof(char))))){
            data = p;
        }
        else{
            printf("realloc error\n");
            throwInternError();
        }
        data[strlen(data)+1] = '\0';
        data[strlen(data)] = c;
        return data;
    }
}
```

This is how I use addDataChunk:

```
temp_char =getc(pFile);
temp_string=addDataChunk(temp_string,temp_char);
```

When I do these two lines:

```
printf("%s\n","Hello\nWor'ld\\\042");
printf("%s\n",temp_string);
```

I get this:

```
Hello
Wor'ld\"
Hello\nWor'ld\\\042
```

Do somebody know why the output is different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show a [mcve], otherwise the question will be quickly downvoted/closed.

Comment: I have editted the question.

Comment: @nocturne your question is somewhat  better now, but it's still not a [mcve] where we can copy/paste from the question into and editor and compile. We have no clue how you use the `addDataChunk` function.

Comment: The complete program is so complex, it would not fit there. The purpose of program is reading from .txt, where is exactly this string `Hello\nWor'ld\\\042`, When I read char after char, I am calling function `addDataChunk`, in the end when I print the output of string in file and my stored string, they are different.

Comment: That's what "Minimal" means. You are not supposed to give us your complete program. You are supposed to create a **minimal** program that is **complete** that shows what you intend to ask.

Comment: String literals are escaped. In `"Hello\nWor'ld\\\042"` a "\\" represents a single backslash and so on. On the other hand when you read such a string from a file no escaping is done. A backslash is a backslash when read.

Comment: As always: Please don't cast the return of `malloc` & co in C. It's required in C++, but frowned upon in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your texte file contains

> Hello\nWor'ld\\042

Now if you read this file character by character with `getc` you will get the characters verbatim, that means you will get successively:

`H`, `e`, `l`, `l`,`o`,`\`,`n`, ..., `\`, `\`, `\`, `0`, `4`, `2`.

On the other hand the [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) `"Hello\nWor'ld\\\042"` will be transformed by the compiler into:

`H`, `e`, `l`, `l`,`o`,`\n`, ..., `\`, `"`.

Actually `\n` will be translated into the ASCII character 10 (line feed), `\\` will be translated into `\` and `\042` will be translated into the ASCII character whose value in octal is 042 that is `"`.

You should read about [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Answer (score -2):

Please use this:

```
char* temp_string = "Hello\n world\\\042";
printf(" %s","Hello\nworld\\\042\n");
printf("%s",temp_string);
```